# How to validate a TextIO argument?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am just coming to terms with Python type hinting and I am confused how to implement argument validation for the following function signature:

```py
def read_file(file: Union[str, PathLike, TextIO]) -> str:
```

My initial attempt at a pythonic implementation was the following:

```py
def read_file(file: Union[str, PathLike, TextIO]) -> str:
    try:
        with open(file) as fileIO:
            return read_file(fileIO)
    except TypeError:
        return file.read()
```

Although this seems like a totally valid pythonic implementation for `read_file`, the type checker went all over this one. This is understandable since `open` does not accept any of the possible types except `TypeIO` and there is nothing to narrow the type down (although it is surprising that the `except TypeError:` is not considered).

So I gave up on "asking for forgiveness" and instead tried to explicitly check the argument:

```py
def read_file(file: Union[str, PathLike, TextIO]) -> str:
    if isinstance(file, TextIO):
        return file.read()
    else:
        with open(file) as fileIO:
            return read_file(fileIO)
```

This turns the whole logic around and checks if file is `TextIO` so the type checker is all happy. The problem is that this actually makes no sense at runtime since `TextIO` is not actually a base class you can check against, but rather a type that exists only for type hinting.

Now this is where I started to get really confused, since I realized I actually had no idea how to go about checking whether something is a `TextIO` at runtime. I dug through all kinds of rabbit holes for checking if a variable is either a path-like or file-like, but it all feels like I'm missing something fundamental here. I mean, if the type checker can know ahead of time that something is `TextIO` then how can it be hard to narrow down the type in the implementation?

This must be something that is done in all kinds of libraries, but most implementations I found use vague checks for `read` and iterable, etc. perhaps for backwards compatibility, but I'm aiming for python 3.9+ so was hoping that by now there might be a better solution.

**NOTE**: As a clarification given comments and existing answers. I am not asking about what is the correct implementation for opening text files. I am also not asking how to use type hinting *in general*: I understand that you are supposed to use type narrowing to get the type checker happy.

**My question is**: what functions or expressions can you use in your code to do type narrowing specifically of `TextIO` type hints so that the compiler will be happy to discard that type for a variable? `try.. except` doesn't work, checking if value is instance of `TextIOBase` or `TextIO` also doesn't work.

Comment: `try…except` on a call expression when you don’t know the arguments passed may be common in untyped Python, which (I’m guessing) is why you’re calling it “pythonic”. This is **not** how you would do things in static typing in Python or any other language with static type checking. Use this instead: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html

Comment: @dROOOze did you read the question to the end?

Comment: I don't recommend writing a function that does this much. Make the caller responsible for providing a file-like object as an argument.

Comment: @chepner this is not part of the question, but there are plenty of examples of functions that do exactly this much, just need to look at numpy, pandas and any number of libraries that pull data out of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html), paying very careful attention to how you order the type tests in the clauses of a type-narrowing block. Specifically, for types which are difficult to test, use the "catch-all" clause to catch the type, which is:

- the `else` clause in `if...elif...else` blocks;
- the [wildcard pattern `_` in `match...case` blocks](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-a-wildcard).

The following example can be checked on [mypy-play.net](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=97258254e9bf0edca6c66742c00d35db) and [pyright-play.net](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBBAzgKFJWcYE8zAHYDmcAhopssgCYCmAZnFNcZQPq3AA21AFO1wFxxEMKHAA%2BCRADoACsRgALADLAA1tQDawqAF1xmKQBVqADxgBJAPIBKOAFoAfEJH9kcd3GD1gifMOJ4AMY8fNQANHDc2hFIsvLKatTW1q4eaXAA7sCKCGDUeLycSSRkoVap6ZWMMACuUHgMTKyhhVxW1m4e1ByI1BVV1LX1cKFSjMzcHUA):

```py
import os
import typing as t

def read_file(file: str | os.PathLike[str] | t.TextIO) -> str:
    if isinstance(file, (str, os.PathLike)):  # Type(s) which can be tested at runtime
        with open(file) as fileIO:
            return read_file(fileIO)
    else:  # Type(s) which can't be tested at runtime
        return file.read()
```

If your type checker supports type narrowing using `hasattr`, this could be an option as well ([mypy-play.net](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=587d9909d5832af9f1b414fe87fab409)):

```
import os
import typing as t

def read_file(file: str | os.PathLike[str] | t.TextIO) -> str:
    if hasattr(file, "read"):
        return file.read()
    else:  # Definitely not `typing.TextIO`, which has `read`
        with open(file) as fileIO:
            return read_file(fileIO)
```

Comment: Great answer, and great examples on type hinting validation by exclusion, and available strategies for different checkers, thanks. I had no idea that some checkers supported narrowing using `hasattr`.

Comment: @glopes I made a mistake in the `hasattr` explanation, fixed now - it works in simpler situations such as this one, but is problematic if you need to check more members in a union.